# OptimisticLockException org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException during insertion in DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to build a meal booking system, where the logic is as follows:

1. select query to check if the user has already booked a meal,
2. if select query returns 0 then insert into the table

I have only one table `meal_booking`, which is used for storing the meal booking status details.

This works fine in normal cases. But whenever there is a load on the system, I am getting
`OptimisticLockException`  `org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException`

I am using Spring Boot and Hibernate JPA.

My DAO Layer Code:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class MealBookingDAO {

private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
public MealBookingDAO(EntityManager theEntityManager) {
    entityManager = theEntityManager;
}

public Object bookMeal(Map < String, Object > payload) {

    Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    try {
        String countQuery = "select count(sm.id) as count from meal_booking where meal_id = " + payload.get("mealId");

        NativeQuery countQuery = currentSession.createNativeQuery(countQueryString);

        List < Object > countResult = countQuery.getResultList();

        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

        BigInteger data = (BigInteger) countResult.get(0);

        if (data.intValue() == 0) {

            String insertQueryString = "insert into meal_booking(`user_id`, `meal_id`, `status`) values (?,?,?)";

            int inserted = entityManager.createNativeQuery(insertQueryString).setParameter(1, payload.get("userId"))
                .setParameter(2, payload.get("mealId")).setParameter(3, payload.get("status")).executeUpdate();
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your query you can add additional hints to lock a row and prevent others from updating it.

```
    this.setLockMode(lockMode ?: LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    .setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", duration ?: LockOptions.WAIT_FOREVER)
    .setHint("javax.persistence.lock.scope", scope ?: PessimisticLockScope.NORMAL)
```

Be sure to check out:
[Pessimistic locking](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking)